# Symfony huge datetime object with hundreds of transitions in timezone

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3, symfony4, symfony-3.4

After retrieving an entity object my datetime columns shown hundreds of this attribute inside the timezone:

```
 <transitions>
    <ts>-9223372036854775808</ts>
    <time>-292277022657-01-27T08:29:52+0000</time>
    <offset>-28378</offset>
    <isdst>0</isdst>
    <abbr>LMT</abbr>
  </transitions>
```

What the hell is this? 
It is making the object unmanageable, in every datetime column is pulling hundreds of transitions inside the timezone.

Comment: show your entity, please

Comment: Can you elaborate .... "unmanageable" because of?

Comment: @Rwly have you find the solution for this problem?